# removing multiple files from a web-directory using foreach() function

Tags: php

I want to delete multiple files from my directory, and for this I am using the following code

```
$x=array(".index.php",".code.html","about.txt");
 foreach($x as $a)
 unlink($a);
```

The wired thing with this code is that it sometime works and sometimes doesn't, and no errors.

Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: Why do you use dot in begining of ile's name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some monitoring to your code, to see what happens:

```
foreach($x as $a) {
    echo "File $a ";
    if (file_exists($a)) {
        if (is_file($a)) {
            echo "is a regular file ";
        } else {
            echo "is not a regular file ";
        }
        if (is_link($a)) {
            echo "is a symbolic link ";
        }
        if (is_readable($a)) {
            echo " readable";
        } else {
            echo " NOT readable";
        }
        if (is_writeable($a)) {
            echo " and writeable ";
        } else {
            echo " and NOT writeable ";
        }
        echo "owned by ";
        echo posix_getpwuid(fileowner($a)) ['name'];
        if (unlink($a)) {
            echo "- was removed<br />\n";
        } else {
            echo "- was NOT removed<br />\n";
        }
    } else {
        echo "doesn't exist<br />\n";
    }
}
```

Also read [this comment on the PHP manual page](https://php.net/unlink#101637) about unlinking files.

If you have to use a path for your file, convert it to a real path with the function `realpath()` - see https://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php